# Unable to up vagrant due to invalid OpenPGP in Ubuntu 16

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, portia

I am trying to install Portia Scrawlhub using vagrant in Ubuntu version 16. 
When i give " sudo vagrant up " in terminal i get the following error.
Could someone please help me in this regards.

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.36
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/nn/Downloads/portia-master
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20160909-3538-1mj5bwh.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: APP_ROOT=/vagrant
==> default: Executing command: install_deps
==> default: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.3yWEJelTfE --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ABF5BD827BD9BF62
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: requesting key 7BD9BF62 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
==> default: ?: 
==> default: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection refused
==> default: gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: no valid OpenPGP data found.
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: Total number processed: 0
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Comment: Are you running this behind a proxy or some kind of firewall? The problems seems to be that your vagrant couldn't connect to keyserver.ubuntu.com

Comment: Im using office network, but not all websites are blocked here.

Comment: Am able to connect to the link keyserver.ubuntu.com through browser.

Comment: Please try `telnet keyserver.ubuntu.com 11371` from the command line. If it says `connected to keyserver.ubuntu.com`, you're okay, if not, it's your network.

Comment: Am getting the same error "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused".

Comment: Your network is blocking access to the keyserver. Do you have a proxy set in your browser, that you're using?

Comment: there is no specific proxy, is there any way i can run vagrant without getting into this link

Answer (score 1):

The log indicates that Vagrant works just fine. When Vagrant tries to fire up the VM and run the commands it's been asked to, it fails. The failure is because OP is unable to access `keyserver.ubuntu.com` on port `11371`, which seems to be blocked on the network.

The correct fix is to change the network firewall/access rules to allow access to keyservers, or at least `keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371`.

The work around would be to attempt to modify the Vagrant file so that the following command:

```
gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.3yWEJelTfE --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ABF5BD827BD9BF62
```

is changed to

```
gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.3yWEJelTfE --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys ABF5BD827BD9BF62
```

Note that the argument to the `--keyserver` flag has changed from `keyserver.ubuntu.com` to `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80`. [1]

[1] Using https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1101366&p=10043037#post10043037 as reference.

Comment: In Vagrant file under which attribute i should include this?